# Using addHeaderView in Android

Tags: android-listview

On clicking the button following happens to the ListView:
1. Through addHeaderView the header is displayed.
2. SimpleCursorAdapter displays data from the database table.
Now when I click the button again then the header duplicates, in the list while the data from the table is correctly displayed.This keeps happening every time the button is clicked.How to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Adapter does not provide HeaderView-s and doesn't count them.

Use *ListView.getHeaderViewsCount()* to get the number of header views. This is how you can avoid adding unnecessary views.